# Delete a key of a list of dicts within a list of dicts

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

I have a list of dicts within a list of dicts and I would like to delete the key `options` that is part of the list of dictionaries in `questions`. I haven't been able to find a solution so far, what would be the best way to do this?

```
[{'id': 1,
  'type': 'FIXED',
  'questions': [
   {'id': 79401,
    'options': {'labels': {'left': 'No',
      'right': 'Yes'}}}],
{'id': 2,
 'type': 'MULTI',
 'questions': [
   {'id': 79402,
    'options': {'randomize': 'none',
    'captionText': '...'}}]}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over the nested lists with a nested `for` loop, and then you can `del` the key you want to delete:

```
>>> data = [{'id': 1,
...   'type': 'FIXED',
...   'questions': [
...    {'id': 79401,
...     'options': {'labels': {'left': 'No',
...       'right': 'Yes'}}}]},
... {'id': 2,
...  'type': 'MULTI',
...  'questions': [
...    {'id': 79402,
...     'options': {'randomize': 'none',
...     'captionText': '...'}}]}]
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> for d in data:
...     for q in d['questions']:
...         del q['options']
...
>>> pprint(data)
[{'id': 1, 'questions': [{'id': 79401}], 'type': 'FIXED'},
 {'id': 2, 'questions': [{'id': 79402}], 'type': 'MULTI'}]
```